# How to render an AE project on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, adobe, rendering, after-effects

I've got a 2012 MacBook Pro that has been holding strong for most tasks to this day, though it would appear rendering video seems to be its breaking point.

I read that it was possible to render an After Effects project on the Google Cloud Platform, however, I can't find any tutorials on how it could be done.

I'm not really looking to purchase a $3,000 rendering station right now, which is why I am pursuing the Google Cloud option under the assumption that it would be cheaper but please correct me if there is a better alternative.

The video I want to render is about 30min long @ 30fps.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use a Windows compute engine.
Depending of the video quality you want, it would be a good idea to use a GPU instance.

Here is a link to a [google tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/creating-a-virtual-gpu-accelerated-windows-workstation).

Comment: The video quality would be 1080p for YouTube, would a GPU instance be a good fit for that?

Comment: You have many choice for your GPU : GPU NVIDIA Tesla K80, P100, P4 et V100. I think you will found what you need !