# Is it possible to render a video from AfterEffects in a Google Collaboratory notebook?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, video, graphics, jupyter-notebook

I have an AfterEffects video ready to be exported in `mp4` format, but my PC has not a good processor or graphics card. I have also been using `Google Colab` for a while and I wonder if I could use its GPU computing power to accelerate the render process of any project made with After Effects or a similar application.

I have searched but I didn't find any solution to this problem, although some applications like Blender can be used with `Colab` notebooks.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585083/how-to-render-an-ae-project-on-google-cloud-platform) and the answer was to use a Windows compute engine. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/creating-a-virtual-gpu-accelerated-windows-workstation) are the steps of how to create a virtual GPU-accelerated Windows workstation in GCP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render an AE project on Google Cloud Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585083/how-to-render-an-ae-project-on-google-cloud-platform)